# Resolving peer dependencies for build in NPM

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, material-ui, vite

I've been having a day trying to figure out some peer dependency issues. Things run fine in development mode, but when I build I get errors like "error TS2786: 'Chart' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its type 'typeof Chart' is not a valid JSX element type.". The chart in question is react-google-charts chart, so it surely is a valid jsx element. When running npm run build I get:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @mui/utils@5.14.19
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/utils
npm ERR!     @mui/utils@"^5.14.19" from @mui/material@5.14.19
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       @mui/material@"^5.14.19" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@mui/icons-material)
npm ERR!     @mui/utils@"^5.14.19" from @mui/system@5.14.19
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/system
npm ERR!       @mui/system@"^5.14.19" from @mui/material@5.14.19
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!         @mui/material@"^5.14.19" from the root project
npm ERR!         1 more (@mui/icons-material)
npm ERR!     2 more (@mui/private-theming, @mui/base)
npm ERR!   15 more (react-router-dom, @emotion/react, react-native-web, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/icons
npm ERR!     @material-ui/icons@"^4.11.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!     @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/icons
npm ERR!       @material-ui/icons@"^4.11.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "preinstall": "npm install --package-lock-only --ignore-scripts && npx npm-force-resolutions",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.5.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.5.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.19",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.19",
    "electron": "^27.1.3",
    "html2canvas": "^1.3.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.9",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.10.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "typescript": "^4.6.5",
    "vite": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

I have tried all sorts of reinstalls, cache clears, --force and --legacy-peer-deps tags, nothing seems to quite fix it. I have also tried suppressing the ts errors, but then when I do build, the build does not actually work. Everything works great in dev mode - I wish I could package up that model. Thanks so much for the help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a [deprecated version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/core) of Material UI, which only works with React 16 or React 17 and has stopped receiving updates in September 2021.

To use Material UI with React 18, you'll need to go for [its latest version](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/) (currently `v5.14.19`).

If, for any reason, you want to keep using Material UI `v4.12.4`, you'll have to downgrade React to latest stable `v16` or latest stable `v17`.

---

As a side-note, using React 18 with React 17 type definitions might lead to unexpected behavior and build errors. Use the type definitions for the React major version used in the project.